# How to turn a PDF document upside down

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, libreoffice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save rotated Adobe pdf file?](https://superuser.com/questions/145696/how-to-save-rotated-adobe-pdf-file)

I'd like to rotate by 180 degrees each page in a high-resolution .pdf, but don't know how.   In ImageMagick, using 'convert -flip -flop' lowers the resolution significantly, while increasing the file size slightly.  This also happens (to a lesser extent) in LibreOffice, an example of open-source PDF editors.  Any ideas, besides buying Adobe Acrobat?  (which may or may not solve the problem!)

Comment: You can turn your monitor 180 degrees.

Comment: Thanks, I read the solution there which suggests PDFcreator.  Printing from Adobe Reader in Windows XP, I don't see a 'rotate' option in PDFcreator.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

PDF Split and Merge (pdfsam) has a processing option to rotate PDFs.

http://www.pdfsam.org/?page_id=10

Comment: Thank you, that did it.  (My version of PDFsam was over a year old and didn't have this feature.  Version 2.2 works great: same resolution, and same file size.)  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The free [PDFill PDF Tools](http://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html) can rotate the pdf, entirely or selectively, as well as doing many other useful operations on PDFs.

[image]

Comment: For those finding this answer by Google: You can rotate the PDF by 0 degree, Clockwise 90 degree, 180 degree, Counter Clockwise 90 degree with the above tool.